# Concatenate results from another table

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

I have two tables

```
TableA has three fields
Id | FieldA | SomethingElse

TableB has three fields as well
Id | FieldA_FK | FieldB
```

We can join the tables on

```
TableA.FieldA = TableB.FieldA_FK
```

I would like to select values on both these tables in order to retrieve the following dataset:

```
TableA.Id, TableA.FieldA, TableA.SomethingElse, [Concatenation of TableB.FieldB]
```

To retrieve [Concatenation of TableB.FieldB], I know I can do

```
declare @result varchar(500);
set @result = '';
select @result = COALESCE(@result + ',', '')  + FieldB 
from TableB b 
join TableA a on a.FieldA = b.FieldA_FK
select @result
```

How can I get the result described above with the concatenation on one result row only?

Thanks in advance.

Examples of data:

```
TableA
1   A   something
2   B   somethingElse

TableB
1   A   Aa
2   A   Ab
3   A   Ac
4   B   Ba
5   B   Bb
```

I would like to retrieve

```
1   A   something       Aa, Ab, Ac
2   B   somethingElse   Ba, Bb
```

Comment: so `TableB` has multiple rows for the given `TableA.FieldA`?

Comment: Absolutely, it may have none to multiple rows for each FieldA.

Comment: Why has `TableA` a primary-key `Id` but `TableB` references `TableB` via foreign-key to another column `FieldA` instead of the `Id`-column?

Comment: It is the way the database is designed. I must work with this.

Comment: @cjb110  I added some data examples, It'll help, hopefully.

Comment: I see the answer in the "related" section, on the right side,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084997/how-to-implode-de-normalize-concat-multiple-columns-into-a-single-column?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FOR XML PATH command:

```
SELECT 
    TableA.Id, TableA.FieldA, TableA.SomethingElse,
    [Concatenation of TableB.FieldB] =
    (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + TableB.FieldB AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            FROM TableB
            WHERE (TableA.FieldA = TableB.FieldA_FK) 
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) 
FROM TableA
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f55a/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Works great, Thanks for taking the time Tim, and thanks to you guys who also did.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as obvious as it should be, but you can *abuse* SQL's XML methods:

```
select a.ID, a.FieldA, a.FieldB
, stuff(
   (select ', ' + TableB.FieldB
   from TableB 
   inner join TableA on TableB.TableA_FK = TableA.ID
   for xml path(''), type
   ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
   , 1,2,'')
from TableA a
```

See this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fdd52/5